# Hyphenation of "prerequisite"

Tags: hyphenation

I'm proofreading my thesis, and found that TeX in its infinite wisdom had decided to hyphenate *prerequisite* as pre-req-ui-site. I've replaced it with pre-re-qui-si-te, but I'm a bit unsure what the proper hyphenation is and couldn't find any good sources. Anyone know what's the correct hyphenation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prerequisite), TeX is right. You should (almost) always trust Knuth's brainchild!

Comment: I never would have guessed. I guess I know too much Latin to not see qu as a single unit. =)

Comment: As a native speaker of Portuguese, I appreciate your doubt. English hyphenation is quite different from Romance languages. In Portuguese, for instance, _pré-requisito_ is hyphenated as pré-re-qui-si-to. However, as far as I know, most of the Latin words used in English are hyphenated following the Latin pattern.