# Hyphenation of parameter(s)

Tags: british-english, hyphenation

How is `parameter`(`s`) hyphenated in UK English?

```
   pa-ram-e-ter (Merriam-Webster)
or pa-rame-ter  (Word XP)
or para-met-er  (TCItex)
or para-meter   (OAL Dictionary)
or pa-ra-me-ter (seems to bee the hyphenation of Parameter in German)
or pa-ra-m-e-t-er (combination of all possible locations for hyphenations)
or some other way?
```

Is there a difference for `parameters`? I know that there are rules about the minimum number of letters before the first hyphenation (two letters) and after the last hyphenation (three letters), but those don't appear to be strict rules but more like a recommendation. Or do they prohibit something like "paramet-er" and allow "paramet-ers" (regardless of the hyphenation being right or wrong otherwise)?

As there are differences between US and UK English also regarding hyphenation, please point out if US hyphenation of `parameter`(`s`) is different. (I don't need it, but the information might  be useful for somebody else.)

Comment: In the interest of text formatting?  Break on a syllable.

Comment: @cornbreadninja That doesn't indicate whether the hyphen comes before or after the *t* or the first *r* (for example).

Comment: @AndrewLeach, that was my attempt to make sense of what OP is asking, as _parameter_ is not a normally-hyphenated construction on its own.

Comment: @cornbreadninja, But it might be hyphenated at the end of a line, which is what I guess the OP is asking about. Of course, he may not be...

Comment: @AndrewLeach, that was my guess as well, which is why I advised breaking on a syllable.

Comment: As with [balaclava](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41545/) and [prerequisite](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23230/), these are matters of **typesetting**. I think typesetting is off-topic here on ELU, so I'm voting to close them all.

Comment: Etymologically it is  *para-* and *meter* so that is by far the best place to put a hyphen.

Comment: @cornbreadninja: yes, hyphenation at the end of a line.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm sorry. Could you recommend another (SE) site which would be better suited for such a question, please?

Comment: @Stephen: I never go there, but try [the TEX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) SO site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cornbread says, break on syllable boundaries.

In general, if there are two consonants in a row, you can break between those consonants. So you would break "barter" as "bar-ter", or "inventive" as "in-ven-tive".

If there is a single consonant surround by vowels, break before the consonant. So "customer" is "cus-to-mer".

When there are multiple consonants that make a single sound, like "pl" in "template", you must keep these two letters together. So you could hyphenate that as "tem-plate".

When a suffix like "-ed" or "-ing" or "-en" is added to a word, the break usually comes before the suffix, even when this violates one of the above rules. So "thinking" is "think-ing", not "thin-king".

So "parameter" can be broken "pa-ra-me-ter".

There are many special cases and exceptions. This is what keeps English lively.

Comment: That is the breaking I would have guessed, but with the different breaking points in the references I feared to be wrong. Thus it is now "pa-ra-me-ter" for me. Thanks, +1 and accepted.

Comment: The hyphenation *cus-to-mer* disagrees with many [dictionaries](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/customer), because *custom* is a word and one of the rules of hyphenation (that this answer completely neglects) is that you put your breaks at morpheme boundaries. (Not just for suffixes like *-ed*, *-ing*, etc).

Comment: @PeterShor Hmm, you're right, I checked several dictionaries and they all broke it cus-tom-er. I find this surprising because, while "-er" is a common suffix that indeed would be broken like that in a word like, say, "renter" or "employer", I thought that here that was simply a coincidence. A customer is not someone who customs. :-) Perhaps light would be shed on this by studying the etymology.

Comment: @Jay: A customer is somebody who gives you custom. [Oxford Dictionaries:](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/custom) **custom**: *British [mass noun]* Regular dealings with a shop or business by customers.

Comment: Both *custom* and *customer* come to English from Latin and French, and a quick Google search didn't untangle the etymology of the various meanings. But this apparently didn't stop the dictionary compilers from considering that *-er* was a suffix on *custom* (which it originally was in at least one of these languages).

Answer (score -2):

Some more confusion to this. Oxford on-line dictionary lists the following hyphenation:

par|am¦eter

I couldn't figure out if there is a difference between | or ¦.  In doubt, I will stick to the Merrian-Webster hyphenation.

Comment: “|” indicates a recommended hyphenation. “¦” indicates a possible, but not recommended hyphenation. Suggesting that the asker stick to Merriam-Webster (which is American) is hardly useful in a question that specifically states that _UK_ English is needed.